# unwrapping org links to leave just the link text

Tags: org-mode

Is there quick and dirty way to convert:

```
[[http://foo.com][everything you need to know about foo]]
```

to simply:

```
everything you need to know about foo
```

Comment: Your question is formulated rather vaguely. Do you want to replace the link at point with the description or do you want to replace each link in a org file with its description? Do you want to make the replacements interactively or programmatically? Note that you used plural in the heading but just one example link in the body of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following elisp-code defines a command `org-link-at-point-unlink` that replaces the link at point with its contents. Thereby "contents" means the link description.

```el
(require 'subr-x) ;; for `when-let'

(defun org-link-at-point-unlink ()
  "Replace link at point with description."
  (interactive)
  (when-let ((el (org-element-context))
         (b (and (eq (org-element-type el) 'link)
             (org-element-property :contents-begin el)))
         (e (org-element-property :contents-end el))
         (contents (buffer-substring-no-properties b e))
         (b (org-element-property :begin el))
         (e (org-element-property :end el)))
    (delete-region b e)
    (insert contents)))
```

Comment: it reports `replace-region` is undefined, what am I missing?

Comment: I used `(delete-region b e) (insert contents)` and that worked. Thank you for that snippet, I learned a few new things.

Comment: @Agzam I am sorry about `replace-region`. That was from my personal configuration. I should have tried the elisp snippet with `emacs -Q`! I adopted your suggestion now. Thanks.